# sql add iterated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this

```
| Id | FirstName    | LastName  | UniqueNumber |
|----|--------------|-----------|--------------|
| 1  | Marie        | Roberts   |              |
| 2  | Howard       | Turner    |              |
| 3  | Larry        | Phillips  |              |
| 4  | Mildred      | Foster    |              |
```

There are over than 50k records, I need to fill UniqueNumber column base on first letter from first name and first letter from last name, additional I need to add specific 4 digits number. For example take a look at first row Marie Roberts, UniqueNumber column should be fill like this: MR0001, but when next record will start with the same Initials the numbers should be MR0002. Right now I have query like this:

```
DECLARE @Iterator int = 1
SELECT Id       
        ,FirstName
        ,LastName
        ,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(FirstName, 1,1), SUBSTRING(LastName, 2,1)) AS [Initials]
        ,LAG(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(FirstName, 1,1), SUBSTRING(LastName, 2,1))) OVER (order by FirstName, LastName) AS [PreviousInitials]
        ,CASE
            WHEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(FirstName, 1,1), SUBSTRING(LastName, 2,1)) = LAG(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(FirstName, 1,1), SUBSTRING(LastName, 2,1))) OVER (order by FirstName, LastName) THEN @Iterator+1
            ELSE 1
        END as [TempNumber]
  FROM [TEST].[dbo].[Person] 
  order by FirstName, LastName
```

And results looks:

```
| Id    | FirstName | LastName  | Initials      | PreviousInitials      | TempNumber
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 94    | Aaron     | Bailey    | AB            | NULL                  | 1
| 193   | Aaron     | Bailey    | AB            | AB                    | 2
| 292   | Aaron     | Bailey    | AB            | AB                    | 2
| 391   | Aaron     | Bailey    | AB            | AB                    | 2
| 490   | Aaron     | Bailey    | AB            | AB                    | 2
| 589   | Aaron     | Bailey    | AB            | AB                    | 2
| 688   | Aaron     | Bailey    | AB            | AB                    | 2
| 787   | Aaron     | Bailey    | AB            | AB                    | 2
| 886   | Aaron     | Bailey    | AB            | AB                    | 2
| 985   | Aaron     | Bailey    | AB            | AB                    | 2
| 938   | Adam      | Russell   | AR            | AB                    | 1
| 740   | Adam      | Russell   | AR            | AR                    | 2
```

Problem appeared in case statement I cannot incremented @Iterator variable.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `row_number()`:

```
select p.*,
       (left(firstname) + left(lastname) +
        right('0000' +
              convert(varchar(255),
                      row_number() over (partition by left(firstname) + left(lastname) order by id
                     ), 4
              )
       ) as uniquenumber
from [TEST].[dbo].[Person] p
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Initialy this solution doesn't works but when I added order by firstName, lastName at the end it works as I expected:

```
  select p.*,
       (left(p.FirstName, 1) + SUBSTRING(LastName, 2,1) +
        right(('0000' +
              convert(varchar(255),
                      row_number() over (partition by left(firstname, 4) + left(lastname, 4) order by id
                     ), 4
              )), 4
       )) as uniqueUi
from [TEST].[dbo].[Person] p
order by p.FirstName, p.LastName
```